# Python and Variable Scope

Tags: python, class, methods, scope, class-variables

So I am recently new to Python, but I seem to be able to program some stuff and get it working.  However I've been trying to expand my knowledge of how things work in the language, and putting this simple file together confuses me.

```
class TestA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.varNum = 3

    def printNum(self):
        print(self.varNum)


class TestB:
    varNum = 0

    def __init__(self):
        varNum = 3

    def printNum(self):
        global varNum
        print(varNum)

a = TestA()
a.printNum()

b = TestB()
b.printNum()
```

The code to `TestA` prints 3 to the screen properly.  However the code for `TestB` instead gives me a `NameError` stating that: `'varNum' is not defined`.  And I get that error whether i have the `global varNum` line there or not.

I suppose what confuses me, is I see the `__init__` function as a class constructor.  And when I have programmed with languages such as Java or C# I've declared global variables outside of the constructor so that their scope is the whole class.  Is that not a thing in Python?  The code I've written I just kind of tagged `self.` onto everything because I was just trying to get some stuff put together quickly, but I am trying to figure more out about the language now.  Is `self.` the only way in Python to make class scope variables?  Or are there other ways?

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: `self.foo` isn't class-scoped, it's instance-scoped.

Comment: (And what Python calls "global" is module-scoped).

Comment: So `self.foo` is scoped for the instance of that class's object, and global pertains to the scope of each `.py` file? Huh.  Thank you.

Comment: Right. If you have `a=1` at the top of your script (in module scope), and then `a=2` somewhere inside a function or class, the `a=2` is creating or changing a local variable instead of the module-scoped variable *unless* you precede it with `global a`, which is the extent of what `global` means in Python.

Comment: ...that said -- this is a pretty questionable question, as they go. If it were more clear and specific, we could probably mark it duplicative of another preexisting question about scoping in Python, but right now it's so fuzzy that it's hard to tell if another given question is or is not about the same thing. And having fuzzy boundaries is actually grounds for closing a question in and of itself.

Comment: If you were **just** asking why `testB` throws the given error, that would be clear and not at all fuzzy, but it's not clear that that's the limit of this question's scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python, variables declared inside the class definition, but not inside a method are class or static variables:

```
class TestB:
    varNum = 0
```

This creates a class-level `varNum` variable, but this is distinct from any instance-level `varNum` variable, so you could have:

```
class TestB:
    varNum = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.varNum = 3

b = TestB()
print(b.varNum)  # print 3
print(TestB.varNum)  # print 0
```

Thus, class `TestB` should work in this way:

```
class TestB:
    varNum = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.varNum = 3

    def printInstanceNum(self):
        print(self.varNum)    

    def printClassNum():
        print(TestB.varNum)

b = TestB()
b.printInstanceNum()  # print 3
TestB.printClassNum()  # print 0
```

Note that since there's no any reference to instance object in method `printClassNum()`, we don't have to put `self` as an argument. The method could actually become a staticmethod:

```
class TestB:
    varNum = 0    

    @staticmethod
    def printClassNum():
        print(TestB.varNum)
```

#### Ref

- [class objects](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects)
- [static method](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#staticmethod)

Comment: "Static"? That's a completely different thing. These are **class** variables (as opposed to **instance** variables).

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation :)

Comment: Discussing static **methods** in a question about **variable** scope seems rather like conflating unrelated things.